# Too many open files in linux we are closing file descriptor

Tags: linux, bash, gdb, sh, ulimit

We are facing too many open files in linux server and we already increase ulimits to maximum.

I am planning to close file descriptor using gdb command and then close fd for pid which I am looking for.

Will that solve issue of too many files, we are also looking solution to fix this from application .

Can anyone suggest closing fd by using gdb will solve our problem? Please suggest.

Comment: It sounds like you have a design flaw in your program. Why do you have so many files open at the same time?

Comment: Yes I agree, we are fixing it and tuning it,  however we are planning to reduce risk on prod, wr will execute that script

Comment: When executing lsof command it giving 26k files on server.

Comment: What kind of program is it that has most of them open?

Comment: . TTF fonts are open and watermark pdf

Comment: I wondered more about which _program_ it is that keeps so many of the files open.

Comment: It's our application deployed in jboss application, application written in java

Comment: I suspect that even if you could force the file to be closed, it's going to create a situation the process expecting it to be open can't handle, causing it to crash anyway. In that case, you may as well just kill the process (which will automatically reclaim the file handle).

Comment: When opening your files are you using `try` _-with-resources_ to get them automatically closed when you are done with them?

Answer (score 0):

> When executing lsof command it giving 26k files on server.

It seems unlikely that you have 26K *distinct* `.ttf` font files on the system.

This suggests that you open the *same* `.ttf` font multiple times, or that you are leaking file descriptors.

You should *definitely* fix the FD leak (if there is one) -- no amount of manually closing FDs is going to let the server work -- it will simply run into the same problem after a while.

For the "open the same file many times", the usual solution is to introduce a font cache -- before opening a file, check the font cache and use data from it if it's already been opened. This may increase memory consumption, but eliminate the "open many times" problem.

Memory consumption could be managed (if necessary) by using appropriate cache expiration policy.

Comment: We are doing the same, can you please suggest mean time can we use gdb close

Comment: Now this issue is  resolved this is because of pdfbox version 2.0.4 . in that version leakage of .ttf files,  this issue is solved in 2.0.12 version , we used 2.0.25 . It solve this issue. we also used  linux script  for one day to close connection on server  , gdb $pid and then p close(fd)